# Flask ejecutar función python sin recargar la pagina

Tags: python, flask

y gracias por adelantado.
Estoy empezando con Flask y ando un poco perdido.

Tengo una tabla donde he cargado una serie de imágenes, unos datos referentes a las mismas y un botón para grabar las imágenes con sus datos. El caso es que no se como llamar a la función que deber grabar la imagen sin refrescar la página y perder todos los datos de las demás imágenes.

Hay alguna forma de llamar a una función directamente desde la plantilla??

[image: vista aplicacion]

```
<td style="vertical-align:middle;" >
                        <center>
     <a href="{{ url_for('grabarimagen', nombre = element[4]) }}" class="btn btn-success">Grabar Imagen</a>
                        </center>
</td>
```

Comment: Deberías plantear una solución con javascript

Answer (score 1):

He conseguido ejecutar una funcion utilizando ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

<! -- This script runs the python script when the button is clicked -->
<script>
    function myfunction_clickevent(){
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url:"/test",
            context: document.body }
           
        });
    }
</script>

@app.route('/test', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    print('hola mundo',text)
    return render_template('grabar.html',fileupload=True)
```

Así me funciona, me imprime el hola mundo y no me actualiza la pagina. Lo que no consigo es poder pasar parámetros a la función, me gustaría pasar como parámetros los datos que tengo en el formulario para poder grabarlos en en una base de datos.

Alguien sabe como puedo pasar los parámetros?

Comment: Esto en realidad debe ser una edición a tu pregunta (ya que esta respuesta no responde al 100% a la pregunta que has hecho). Si ya lo resolviste, no olvides en ese caso editar tu respuesta, como para poder completarla.

Answer (score -2):

Yo lo uso de la siguiente manera:

https://wiki.nuxpy.com/index.php/Flask:_carga_de_contenido_usando_jQuery

Y usando jQuery.

Saludos.

Comment: En vez de dejar solo un enlace, puedes hacer un resumen o resaltar las partes mas importantes de la informacion que proporciona ese enlace. Si el enlace deja de servir tu respuesta pierde todo sentido. Lee [answer]

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/369717)